# Looking for YA series about kid colonists on a supposedly deserted planet

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I'm looking for a YA science fiction series that I read in the early 90s. I think I found the series around 1991, but I think it was a fairly recent series at the time. I know it went past book 6, and it strikes me it was supposed to be one of those mass-produced books with many titles in the series. I remember they had the generic white binding with a color image in front.

The series was about 5 or 6 teens whose families had moved to a new planet to colonize it. I remember one boy had moved from a planet (Arcadia?) with a slightly heavier gravity. The new planet was slightly unstable with seismic tremors. In the first novel (I think), the kids went on a school trip and got separated during one of these tremors, and found recordings from the previous inhabitants. There was some indigenous friendly mammals that could repeat words and phrases, but the adults thought they were just mimics. At the beginning of the trip, the creatures would sing "roll me over over over in the clover clover clover". After the kids were rescued after the trip, some of the families were making preparations to leave.

Comment: I have also been trying to find this series. Some more info to maybe help with finding it. 1. They have hover technology, hover bikes that the kids hack to remove safety restraints, and hover transports to move goods from settlement to settlement. 2. I think 1 character was named Philippa, but called Pippa (I think) and she had a criminal past. 3. The “creatures” use telepathic communication, and it changes the teens so they can kind of communicate with each other.